# VESA mode, OSDEV

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, osdev, vesa

I am currently writing an OS from complete scratch(making my own bootloader etc), and I am attempting to adapt VESA mode.
I have read documentation, it all makes sense..all but just a few things.

This is directly from the documentation(I have it implemented differently):

```
vbe_set_mode:
    mov [.width], ax
    mov [.height], bx
    mov [.bpp], cl
 
    sti
 
    push es                 ; some VESA BIOSes destroy ES, or so I read
    mov ax, 0x4F00              ; get VBE BIOS info
    mov di, vbe_info_block
    int 0x10
    pop es
 
    cmp ax, 0x4F                ; BIOS doesn't support VBE?
    jne .error
 
    mov ax, word[vbe_info_block.video_modes]
    mov [.offset], ax
    mov ax, word[vbe_info_block.video_modes+2]
    mov [.segment], ax
 
    mov ax, [.segment]
    mov fs, ax
    mov si, [.offset]
 
.find_mode:
    mov dx, [fs:si]
    add si, 2
    mov [.offset], si
    mov [.mode], dx
    mov ax, 0
    mov fs, ax
 
    cmp [.mode], 0xFFFF         ; end of list?
    je .error
 
    push es
    mov ax, 0x4F01              ; get VBE mode info
    mov cx, [.mode]
    mov di, mode_info_block
    int 0x10
    pop es
 
    cmp ax, 0x4F
    jne .error
 
    mov ax, [.width]
    cmp ax, [mode_info_block.width]
    jne .next_mode
 
    mov ax, [.height]
    cmp ax, [mode_info_block.height]
    jne .next_mode
 
    mov al, [.bpp]
    cmp al, [mode_info_block.bpp]
    jne .next_mode
 
    ; If we make it here, we've found the correct mode!
    mov ax, [.width]
    mov word[vbe_screen.width], ax
    mov ax, [.height]
    mov word[vbe_screen.height], ax
    mov eax, [mode_info_block.framebuffer]
    mov dword[vbe_screen.physical_buffer], eax
    mov ax, [mode_info_block.pitch]
    mov word[vbe_screen.bytes_per_line], ax
    mov eax, 0
    mov al, [.bpp]
    mov byte[vbe_screen.bpp], al
    shr eax, 3
    mov dword[vbe_screen.bytes_per_pixel], eax
 
    mov ax, [.width]
    shr ax, 3
    dec ax
    mov word[vbe_screen.x_cur_max], ax
 
    mov ax, [.height]
    shr ax, 4
    dec ax
    mov word[vbe_screen.y_cur_max], ax
 
    ; Set the mode
    push es
    mov ax, 0x4F02
    mov bx, [.mode]
    or bx, 0x4000           ; enable LFB
    mov di, 0           ; not sure if some BIOSes need this... anyway it doesn't hurt
    int 0x10
    pop es
 
    cmp ax, 0x4F
    jne .error
 
    clc
    ret
 
.next_mode:
    mov ax, [.segment]
    mov fs, ax
    mov si, [.offset]
    jmp .find_mode
 
.error:
    stc
    ret
 
.width              dw 0
.height             dw 0
.bpp                db 0
.segment            dw 0
.offset             dw 0
.mode               dw 0
```

What I am confused about is, why does it assign the segment to the video modes pointer plus 2?
I get that the video mode pointer has an offset:segment, but I am just confused as to why we assign video mode pointer + 2 to the segment, and why we add `si` by two after we assign the offset and segment to the `dx` register.

Comment: the above code is 16-bit, not 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ax, word[vbe_info_block.video_modes]
> mov [.offset], ax
> mov ax, word[vbe_info_block.video_modes+2]
> mov [.segment], ax
> ```

> why does it assign the segment to the video modes pointer plus 2? I get that the video mode pointer has an offset:segment, but I am just confused as to why we assign video mode pointer + 2 to the segment

A far pointer is stored in memory with a word-sized offset followed by a word-sized segment.
The offset is stored at *vbe_info_block.video_modes*, and the segment is stored in the following word which has an address that is 2 more, so at `[vbe_info_block.video_modes + 2]`

> ```
> mov dx, [fs:si]
> add si, 2
> mov [.offset], si
> ```

> and why we add `si` by two after we assign the offset and segment to the `dx` register.

**We don't assign the offset and segment to the `DX` register**!

The far pointer we retrieved (and put in `FS:SI`) points to a list of word-sized mode numbers. It's a mode number that we load in the `DX` register. And the `add si, 2` `mov [.offset], si` is there so the loop can iterate over all the words in the list.